# Angular, what dependency is missing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm learning angular.js and have all libraries linked from CDNs. 
When I try to use `$locationProvider` and `$routeProvider` I get this error:

```
Referee.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider"], 
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

> angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=referee&p1=Error%3A…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A355)

From what I've seen an that error page I need to include `ngRoute`. So I linked `route.min.js` after my `angular.min.js` but it doesn't work and I still get the same error. What do I do wrong?

[Here is jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zededuvoji/edit?html,console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the array syntax is wrong; close the square bracket towards the end:

```
Referee.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", 
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        // ...
    }
]);
```

Why array notation? - [Reason for using array notation when defining AngularJS Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088534/reason-for-using-array-notation-when-defining-angularjs-controller)

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is fine, you just missed a closing tag. You need to take care of all closing tags. so that angular js works awesome

```html
Referee.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", 
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        // ...
    }
]);
```