# AngularJS convert to be minify-friendly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I minify my js scripts, I'm having an error on of `Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- myDirective`

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .run(['$state', run])
    .config(['$provide', config]);

function config($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('myDirective', function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.controller = 'MyController as vm';

        return $delegate;
    })
}
```

It seems like a minify issue wherein it renames variables. Though I'm not sure on how to convert this to be minify-friendly.

Comment: $delegate is minified. So dependency injector will fail to inject the dependency. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18782380/5640621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reason for using array notation when defining AngularJS Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088534/reason-for-using-array-notation-when-defining-angularjs-controller)

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection - Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation) for advice about the pitfalls of that method with respect to minification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs minify best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782324/angularjs-minify-best-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to inject `$delegete` to decorator. you can do this with 2 ways.

one is to create separate function and inject service to that function like this.

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .run(['$state', run])
    .config(['$provide', config]);

function config($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('myDirective', dirFun)
}

dirFun.$inject = ['$delegate'];

function dirFun($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    directive.controller = 'MyController as vm';
    return $delegate;
}
```

option 2

```
function config($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('myDirective',['$delegate',function($delegate) {
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        directive.controller = 'MyController as vm';

        return $delegate;
    }])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function config($provide) {
         $provide.decorator('myDirective' ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
             var directive = $delegate[0];
             directive.controller = 'MyController as vm';

             return $delegate;
         }])
     }
```